# Someone keeps changing my SITEURL (mysql injection or xss?)

Tags: security

I've twice had my site's url changed in the database. This is the only piece of data being altered. Whoever is doing this is then redirecting the site to a script at this location:

```
somelandingpage [dot] com/3gGykjDJ?frm=script
```

I've tried preventing XSS and have checked/updated every single plugin and I cannot figure out how this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably there is some backdoor left on your site. You have to find it, disable it and secure your site for future.

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to deeply look throughout your site for the 'infection'/malware code. This would include the following steps:

- update everything (WP, themes, plugins)
- change credentials on everything (hosting, FTP, admin-level users)
- create a new admin user, log in as it, then delete the user called 'admin' (or demote to 'subscriber')
- look at all folders for files that shouldn't be there. This is somewhat easier if you sort the file list by date, looking for outliers (since you updated everything, the 'good' files should have the same date/timestamp).

I've put together a [procedure](https://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/) I use to clean up a site. It takes a while, but can be done. There are other similar resources available via your favorite search engine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What makes you think there is malware code on the site? Is it possible that this is happening via a mysql injection or xss attack? I checked the dates of all the files/folders and nothing has been changed thank god.

Comment: If the database is getting attacked, then the 'changing passwords on everything' would include the database credentials. There could still be bad code on your site, maybe in theme's functions.php file, or other areas. That's why I recommended deep inspection of all folders after updating everything (even reinstalling themes/plugins from known good source). Looking at the file timestamps of everything (after updates) will alert you to files that may have been modified. And the comment to your question suggested compromised files. My procedure will identify and mitigate any possible attacks.

Comment: As for xss attack, that depends on the quality of the theme/plugin code (and whether you are current on WP versions). Bad code can allow XSS or injection. Most responsible theme/plugin authors will write code to prevent that. Bad programming practices (not sanitizing user input, for example) will have the potential for problems.

Comment: Okay, thank you for following up. I'll follow the procedure list you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fix this:

1. Log onto your PHPMyAdmin.
2. Head to wp_options On line 1 (siteurl) you will notice the 'somelandingpage [dot] com/3gGykjDJ?frm=script' address. Simply edit this line and replace the address with the correct one for your site (Copy the same you see on line 2,     generally something like: https://yoursite.com)
3. This should get rid of the "redirection" and you should be able to log onto your Wordpress Admin Dashboard, from there make sure to update to the
   latest Wordpress version and update all your plugins accordingly.

Hope this helps and saves some of you some time :)